# Custom ListView not working in Android

Tags: android, json

Custom `ListView` adapter is not working
I have designed an adapter to use the object created by Jackson API from a json file. When I am passing the object  to custom adapter to extract the info and populate the ListView but its not working.

Custom Adapter for `ListView`:

```
package adapters;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import entity.VendorListObj;

import plotkai.waterbottle.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomVendorRow extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private VendorListObj[] obj;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public CustomVendorRow(Activity a, VendorListObj[] obj) {
        activity = a;
        this.obj = obj;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View vi = convertView;
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vendor_row, parent, false);
        TextView vName = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.vName);
        TextView distance = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.distance);
        vName.setText(obj[position].getVendorname());
        distance.setText(obj[position].getLocality());

        return vi;
    }

}
```

The xml file of the custom row :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/listbg" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/vName"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Name"
                android:textSize="15dip"
                android:padding="5dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/distance"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Name"
                android:textSize="10dip" 
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the activity calling it is as follows :

```
package plotkai.waterbottle;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

import adapters.CustomVendorRow;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import entity.VendorListObj;

public class VendorList extends Activity {

    ListView list;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_vendor_list);
        Intent i=getIntent();
        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.vendorList);
        String vendorList=i.getExtras().getString("vendorList");
        ObjectMapper mapper =new ObjectMapper();
        VendorListObj[] obj = null;
        try {
        obj=mapper.readValue(vendorList, VendorListObj[].class);
        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        CustomVendorRow vendorRow=new CustomVendorRow(this, obj);
        list.setAdapter(vendorRow);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "list not donee", 3000).show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_vendor_list, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

And the object has the info so no issues with json.
Thanks in advance..:)

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: return size of list from getCount() overridden method currently it is 0 so android is not generating any list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not returning the count of the array.

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return obj.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return obj[position];
}
```

and why dont you use custom objects of arrraylist.